# Embedding a normed space as a hyperplane

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a real normed space and suppose that $X$ is a closed hyperplane of a bigger space $\tilde X$.  Given any unit vector $u$ in $\tilde X\setminus X$, consider the function $p:X\to\mathbb R$ given by $p(x)=\|x+u\|$.

Observe that one may recover the norm structure on $\tilde X$ in terms of $p$ because $\tilde X= X\oplus \mathbb R u$, and for every $x$ in $X$, and every nonzero scalar $\lambda $, one has that
$$
  \|x+\lambda u\| = |\lambda | p\left(\frac x{|\lambda |}\right).
  \tag {$\star$}
  $$

Among the properties satisfied by $p$, one may easily prove that:

1. $p$ is continuous and convex,
2. $\big|\|x\|-1\big|\leq p(x)\leq \|x\|+1$,
3. $\big|p(x)-\|y\|\big|\leq p(x+y)\leq p(x)+\|y\|$,
4. $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to \infty } \frac{p(tx)}t= \|x\|$ (this actually follows from (2)).

**Question**.  What would be a sensible list of properties regarding a function $p:X\to\mathbb R$, perhaps including (1)-(3) above, with which one may prove that ($\star$) defines a norm on $X\oplus \mathbb R$?  Has this problem been considered in the literature?